# Upgraded pip with command line, now Jupyter notebooks dont work

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

So, I decided to upgrade pip using the command line following some instructions over a web page and now when I try to open a Jupyter notebook I just get a blank page with a small message: "This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't, click here to go to Jupyter.", meanwhile the comand line shows the following:

```
    C:\Users\Propietario>jupyter notebook
[I 16:28:26.158 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Propietario
[I 16:28:26.158 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
[I 16:28:26.158 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=767d91ee67804085a541023b7f49efa33d0a3cddb17be4c6
[I 16:28:26.158 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=767d91ee67804085a541023b7f49efa33d0a3cddb17be4c6
[I 16:28:26.159 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:28:26.205 NotebookApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Propietario/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8488-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=767d91ee67804085a541023b7f49efa33d0a3cddb17be4c6
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=767d91ee67804085a541023b7f49efa33d0a3cddb17be4c6
C:\Users\Propietario>jupyter notebook
```

I am not sure if its the path where I upgraded the pip or something like that.

Just checked the version:

```
C:\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

I would apreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: Does the server stop abruptly after giving you the links? What happens when you open those links, is it infinitely loading?

Comment: No further mesagess after those links, and yes when those links are open they try to load but end up giving no response.

Comment: Well, I would try shamnad's answer, or reboot my system. Upgrading pip shouldn't mess with jupyter notebooks. Then I would try upgrading conda/anaconda as well, if you have those.

Answer (score 0):

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

if that doesn't work

```
sudo pkill -1 -f python
```